# How to add Python pep8 exclusion on Spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, spyder, pep8, pycodestyle

How to add Python pep8 exclusions on Spyder mac os?

Added this:

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = W191
```

to this file:
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/.pycodestyle     <-- created this file
and it just gets ignored.
And please, how do I add multiple exclusions?

Comment: usually you create `setup.cfg` in the current working directory

Comment: Would that be the current working directory for Spyder? (Where is it?)

Comment: no idea, I've never used it -- my guess would be the root of the project you're working on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is only possible in Spyder 4. To do it you need to go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Code style`

then activate the option called `Enable code style linting` and finally add your exclusion list in the field called `Ignore the following errors or warnings`.